# nservicebus workers detached after cluster failover

Tags: nservicebus, failover, worker

Background:
We are currently trying to move to the failover cluster distributor model and are seeing some issues when failing over the cluster from one distributor to another. In our lab environment we have set everything up as per [David Boike's blog post](http://www.make-awesome.com/2010/10/deploying-nservicebus-in-a-windows-failover-cluster/). We have 3 servers for this exercise, 2 Dist boxes and 1 worker.

I see the worker initially register to the distributor and it processes messages fine until I initiate a failover test. Once I failover from one node to another, the worker appears to be detached and no longer processes messages. The messages still come in and sit in the clustered MSMQ queue.

I had to restart the nServiceBus Host windows service on the worker to get things going again.

Question: 
Is there a setting that controls how often the worker subscribes to the distributor in case of cluster failover?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you see the worker's ready message in either the control queue or storage queue?

Comment: NSB Version? That blog post was writen for 2.0 and I'm sure is not too relevant for V3 or V4. I tend to shy away failover clusters these days because of weird problems like this that come up.

Comment: Adam - I do not see another worker ready message after failover

Comment: David - we are on 4.0.4 w/ plans to move to 4.0.5 before production launch. This is why I was asking you the other question about SQL server. I was at the point where I was ready to load balance our messages between machines and just use SQL as the shared storage. When you avoid the failover clusters/distributor, what do you usually use in it's place.